# Can you check if i do this recursive method correctly?

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

Here is the question:
There are n switches in the campus. You are required to create a mesh topology for the switches. Write a recursive method to returns the total number of connections required for n switches in the campus.

Output=

Mesh Topology:

There are 4 switches in the campus.

The total number of connections required is 6.

My Code:

```
public class S2L3Q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Mesh Topology");
        TotalConnections(4);
    }

    public static void TotalConnections(int n){
        if(n==0){
            System.out.printf("There are %d switches in the campus",n);
            System.out.println("\nThe total number of connections required is " + n);
        }else{
            System.out.printf("There are %d switches in the campus",n);
            int connect = (n*(n-1))/2;
            System.out.println("\nThe total number of connections required is " + connect);
        }
    }
```

The question ask me to solve it using recursion method, but am i doing it right?

Comment: No, that is not recursion. It would be recursion if you invoked method TotalConnections inside itself.

Comment: In java programming conventions, class start with upper case letter, while methods and variables start with lower case letters. This makes it easier to read Java code from unknown sources (magazine articles, the web and stackoverflow, etc.).

Comment: thank you for the response! I will fix my code again